# Do Instances Share Same Services? - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Lets say i installed two named SQL Server 2008 instances e.g. A and B, will i have two services of each type e.g. two analysis service, two reporting service and so on, one service for A and the other for B? If yes, then it is known a service listens on a port number, how two same services going to listen on the port?

I hope this is clear enough. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: they do not. When you create a second instance, it is listening on a different port than the default instance which, by default, listens on port 1433.

Comment: @peace - That or you can run the SQL Browser service and reference it by instance name (e.g. <servername>\<instance name>). The SQL Browser service will determine the port that under which the instance is running.